# Searching in a collection of sites in Google

Tags: google-search

Using Google Reader, I was able to search for a collection of sites. But, with Google Reader closed I have moved to Feedly. Google Reader had a nice option of searching through the subscribed feeds, which comes with the paid version of Feedly.

I remember using using a Google feature to restrict the Google search to a bunch/collection of sites, but could not recall the same. Could someone let me know the Google feature or anything similar to it?

Comment: I am looking for a better answer, since keeping the Feedly and the Google Custom Search Engine in sync is a pain. So, is the bounty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably thinking of [Google Custom Search Engine](http://www.google.com/cse).

> Google Custom Search enables you to create a search engine for your website, your blog, or a collection of websites. You can configure your search engine to search both web pages and images. You can fine-tune the ranking, customize the look and feel of the search results, and invite your friends or trusted users to help you build your custom search engine. ...
>
> There are two main use cases for Custom Search - you can create a search engine that searches only the contents of one website (site search), or you can create one that focuses on a particular topic from multiple sites. You can use your expertise about a subject to tell Custom Search which websites to search, prioritize, or ignore. Because you know your users well, you can tailor the search engine to their interests.

I use a CSE for several hundred blogs that cover a particular topic of interest and it works great.

Comment: Works like a charm - thnx

Answer (score 2):

Use `OR` to search multiple defined site as `site:website OR site:website OR ...  Search term`

### Example

> site:askubuntu.com OR site:superuser.com user Praveen Sripati badges teacher

### Direct link

http://www.google.com/search?q=site%3aaskubuntu.com+OR+site%3asuperuser.com+user+Praveen+Sripati+badges+teacher

Comment: I have some 100 blogs which I follow, so this is not an elegant solution.